# On button click show another button only in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a table in which each row has three buttons(save, edit, delete). On edit button i want to hide it and want to show save button, also want ot make name column editable.
On save button i want to hide it, and want to show edit button. the html code is bellow.

```
    <table>

        <tr>
          <td class="editablecontent">Name</td>
          <input data-edit type="button" value="Edit">
          <input data-save type="button" value="Save" class="savevarients">
          <input data-delete type="button" value="Delete">
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="editablecontent">Name</td>
          <input data-edit type="button" value="Edit">
          <input data-save type="button" value="Save" class="savevarients">
          <input data-delete type="button" value="Delete">
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="editablecontent">Name</td>
          <input data-edit type="button" value="Edit">
          <input data-save type="button" value="Save" class="savevarients">
          <input data-delete type="button" value="Delete">
         </tr>

    </table>
```

i am using this jquery code but the problem is when i am showing save button it shows i all table, and each row become editable. i want this only on one particulaar row. 
  My js code is bellow.

```
    'click [data-edit]': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $(event.target).hide();
        $(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
        $(".savevarients").show();
    },
    'click [data-save]': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $(event.target).hide();
        $(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', false);
```

Comment: could try using next().show()

Comment: The drawback with `next()` is that it's dependent on the order of the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
$(".savevarients").show();
```

with:

```
$(event.target).parent().find(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
$(event.target).parent().find(".savevarients").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuerys DOM traversal methods to find the nearest `td` to the button which was clicked and base all selectors on that using `find()`. Try this:

```
'click [data-edit]': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var $button = $(event.target).hide();
    var $td = $button.closest(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
    $td.find(".savevarients").show();
},
'click [data-save]': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var $button = $(event.target).hide();
    $button.closest(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`$.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function, for example:

```
$(event.target).siblings(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
$(event.target).siblings(".savevarients").show();
```

I would begin the function by defining the target element:

```
function(event) {
    $target = $(event.target);
    $target.hide();
    $target.siblings(".editablecontent").attr('contenteditable', true);
    $target.siblings(".savevarients").show();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```